# Webgrid to show checked on certain value

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am using webmatrix 2 with razor syntax. One of the fields from my database has value 1 or 0. I want to show the field in my webgrid as a checkbox. Below is the code I have tried:

```
 @grid.GetHtml(    
        tableStyle : "table",
        alternatingRowStyle : "alternate",
        headerStyle : "header",
        columns:
grid.Column(header: "Active", format: (col)=>@Html.Raw("<input type='checkbox'  checked='"+ ((col.Active) ? "checked" :"") + "' disabled='true' />"))
```

I noticed that the above code shows the column with all checkbox checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
grid.Column(
    header: "Active", 
    format: @<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" @Html.Raw(item.Active ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
)
```

This assumes that the `Active` property is boolean on your model and not integer. If it is integer you might adapt the test:

```
grid.Column(
    header: "Active", 
    format: @<input type="checkbox" disabled="true" @Html.Raw(item.Active == 1 ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
)
```